# Tag fires in Google Tag Manager, but it doesn’t show up - AJAX site

Tags: ajax, google-tag-manager

So I’m trying to put a survey onto an Ajax site. I tested the survey to load on page view, refreshed the page and voila, the survey pops up. Now I need it to work when the page doesn’t actually reload.

First I tried triggering the tag on history changes, tag fires in the preview pane, but the survey doesn’t pop up. I then try the lunametrics plugin. On ajaxComplete, I checked the datalayer and created a trigger off the response. Again, tag fires, but the survey doesn’t pop up.

Has anyone else seen this before, where the preview pane says the tag fires, but it doesn’t?